# Why does SE tell others I have edited my question if nobody has viewed it?

Tags: discussion, edits, views, grace-period

If I edit my question five minutes after I ask it, and nobody else has viewed my question yet, then why does Stack Exchange say that I have edited my question?

Comment: Perhaps because you edited your question

Comment: Haha, okay, "Why is the site designed like that?"

Comment: Why should it take the views (or view count) into consideration if it should create an entry in the edit history, or not? How would that improve anything? You already have a 5 minute grace period to edit your question after creating without getting a new history entry (if there is no answer or comment).

Comment: Why do you tell people I edited my post if I edited my post? That seems to be the gist of your question (and it isn't clear why it matters if anyone viewed it or not between edits).

Comment: @Tom I thought the point of showing the edit message was so that people who had previously viewed it would know that the information had changed somehow, so they should re-read the question to see how it is framed differently.

Comment: @ahorn is this a general cause of concern for you? How do you think it could be done better?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter What do you mean by "general"? I only noticed it today, and I think it only becomes apparent on less-used sites. It could be different by not displaying the edit notice if nobody has yet looked at the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question - including its tags - will still appear in the question summary lists, so really the clock should start from the time when it first appears.

Also, implementing what you suggest could encourage questioners to make rapid repeated edits. Whilst editing a question is not itself an issue, it can invalidate answers, so it's best to have the bulk of the question written out from the get-go.

So the current design - where the edit clock starts from the first posting - is the optimal one.

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because of your interesting insight. Theoretically, if people knew that the edit log would only be displayed if another person has seen their question, they would be discouraged from editing it if somebody has seen the question. But, not everybody would know that because not everybody goes into meta posts, and also habit will dictate how people act.

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess that the reason is that "No code is best code".

Absent a compelling UX reason to perform this calculation, it's easier and safer to just use the existing mechanism.

If you think that you have such a compelling use case, please feel free to post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Comment: Interesting answer from a developer's point of view. I wasn't sure whether the issue was deliberate or not, hence why I used the tag [meta-tag:bug], but I will edit.